# Windows Steam not working properly using WineBottler on macOS v10.13.6 (17G3025)

Tags: macos, wine, steam

I've just installed the latest WineBottler v2.0 from https://winebottler.kronenberg.org/downloads.

I clicked on the supplied Steam install button, and ended up with a new application in my application folder - I called it Steam-winebottler.app because I've already got the standard Mac Steam.app.

Steam-winebottler.app launched fine, did various updates, and eventually gave me what looks like a log-in window without any of the usual text.

What I mean is I can see the Steam logo, the Valve logo, and what looks like boxes for password and username entry, but not text saying "Password" or "User name" or "Click to continue" or anything like that.

Here's a screenshot:

[image: WineBottler Steam log-in window]

https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=19444

mentions a problem: Steam client window(s) do(es)n't render any text.

which says "Ensure Steam client is launched as follows...

wine Steam.exe -no-dwrite"

It looks like that's the problem I've got, but I can't see a way to apply the fix when using the WineBottler approach.

I'd appreciate any clues.

Thank you.

Comment: JavaScript is Enabled?

Answer (score -1):

JavaScript is Enabled? I know this is the way a website can look if JavaScript is turned off.

Comment: OP is using a client, not a website, so I'm not clear how this is relevant. Steam does use a browser renderer under the hood, so maybe Javascript is broken, but then how does OP fix it?